# ¿Como consigo el texto de textboxs que se crean en tiempo de ejecución?

Tags: c#

estoy haciendo una aplicación en windows forms, necesito conseguir el texto de unos textboxs (Están en un panel), los cuales se crean en tiempo de ejecución, les dejo el código a ver si me pueden ayudar:

````
        {
            if (z == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < vistaTabla.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.Text = vistaTabla.Columns[b].Name;
                    lbl.Location = new Point(23, y);
                    panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
                    lbl.Show();
                    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
                    textBox.Location = new Point(150, y);
                    panel1.Controls.Add(textBox);
                    textBox.Name = vistaTabla.Columns[b].Name;
                    b++;
                    y = y + 41;
                }
                    z++;
            } ```
````

Comment: Necesitas conseguir el texto del textBox cuando lo introduce o modifica el usuario, no?

Answer (score 3):

Como el control Label lo añades a la colección Controls del contenedor panel1, tan sólo has de mirar en ella para extraer el texto del Label sería así:

```
      foreach (Control item in panel1.Controls)
      {
          if (item.GetType() == typeof(Label))
          {
              // Consultamos el nombre del Label para ver si es el que 
              // estoy buscando
              if (((Label)item).Name == "Mi_Label_Name")
              {
                    // Muestra el texto del LABEL
                    MessageBox.Show(((Label)item).Text);
              }
          }
      }
```

Asegúrate de darle un nombre al label que creas dinámicamente para poder preguntar por el mismo e identificar tu label dentro de todos los controls añadidos a tu contenedor panel1.

Para el Texbox sería lo mismo, solo que añadiríamos un condicional para este tipo de control en el bucle foreach:

```
 if (item.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
 {
     // Consultamos el nombre del TextBox para ver si es el que 
     // estoy buscando
     if (((TextBox)item).Name == "Mi_TextBox_Name")
     {
         // Muestra el texto del TEXTBOX
         MessageBox.Show(((TextBox)item).Text);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Ahora intento y te cuento como me fue.

Comment: ¿Cómo fue?, ¿Se ajusta la respuesta a la solución de tu pregunta?